# Triggered mailing for contacts who did not read a mailing

Tags: 2011, outbound-email

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. I was reading up on Triggered Mailings and what I understood is that the event that triggers the mailing is basically some change in the contact (modifying an extended detail or adding/removing a keyword).

Is it possible to setup a triggered mailing which targets contacts that did not read another mailing? What would be the trigger event in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.

You will want to open the statistics for the Mailing, click on the Sent status (they were sent the e-mail but didn't open it) and save a Dynamic Distribution List based on the results.

Then you simply select that Distribution List in the Triggered Mailing.

However, keep in mind that there is no way to specify a grace period. So it's possible that Contacts would be sent the original Mailing and then shortly afterwards receive the Triggered Mailing -- before they've even had a chance to open it.

So you'd at least want to make sure that the first Mailing was sent out a while ago -- in which case a normal Mailing is probably better than a Triggered Mailing for the follow-up. But either way it's certainly possible to target Contacts who received but did not open a Mailing.

For more information on the steps, have a look at the following documentation page (login required): [Creating Distribution Lists from statistics](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_0923590A3C2243F2B0DFE5F5FFB52F9C)

Comment: Thank you @Peter for your reply. However this seems like a manual process. I was looking for an automated way of doing this. So once the original mailing has been sent out, OE automatically sends a follow up email to recipients who didn't read the email. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Not out of the box, no. Some manual steps would be needed anyway, since you'd need to define the content of the follow-up e-mails. There's an API you can use to somewhat automate it, but be aware that there's no event system yet (so you cannot hook into the creation of new Mailings - you'd have to check at regular intervals)